# Recursive function gives no time to a db query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying building a simple web crawler, but i'm having trouble saving visited links into my Database, here's my code:

```js
function scrape() {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE scraped=false LIMIT 1", (err, res2) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let initialUrl = res2[0].url;
    let dataId = res2[0].id;
    rp(initialUrl).then(function (html) {
      connection.query(`UPDATE dictionary SET scraped=true WHERE id=${dataId}`)
      if (html) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $("a").each(function () {
          if ($(this).attr("href")) {
            let childUrl = $(this).attr("href");
            let pat = /^https?:\/\//i;
            if (pat.test(childUrl)) {
              urlExists(childUrl, (err, existance) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (existance) {
                  connection.query(`SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE url='${childUrl}'`, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (res.length == 0) {
                      console.log(res.length, res, childUrl);
                      connection.query(`INSERT INTO dictionary (url, scraped) VALUES ('${childUrl}', false)`);
                    }
                  })
                };
              });
            };
          };
        });
      };
    })
  })
  setTimeout(scrape, 1000);
}
scrape();
```

Here's the console output before saving links to the db:

[image]

As you can see the last two url make the database trigger, because i've setted the `url` column as `UNIQUE` (cause i want only one "copy" of every url), in fact i've used a second query to check if the url that i'm trying to insert already exists, but it's not working.

Is this something related to the database latecy or something like this?

Comment: Shouldn't the actual scraping go inside a callback to the UPDATE query?

Comment: this qualifies to be a perfect example of why we try to avoid callbacks. any particular reason for doing so ?

Comment: If it's helpful, I wrote [an article](https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/) about better patterns with using MySQL in Node.js, inspired by questions such as these.